# wp_logout not redirecting using wp_logout_url() and wp_redirect()

Tags: logout

I have written this function for loggin user out. The user is loggin out but not redirecting to the page instead goes to home page which default logout Url. i have tried wp_logout_url() and also wp_redirect().

```
function wc_registration_redirect( $redirect_to) {
    wp_logout();
    wp_redirect( '/my-account');
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct method for changing the logout redirect is the `logout_redirect` filter:

```
/**
 * Filters the log out redirect URL.
 *
 * @since 4.2.0
 *
 * @param string  $redirect_to           The redirect destination URL.
 * @param string  $requested_redirect_to The requested redirect destination URL passed as a parameter.
 * @param WP_User $user                  The WP_User object for the user that's logging out.
 */
add_filter( 'logout_redirect', function( $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user ) {
    if ( ! $requested_redirect_to ) { // Don't override the redirect if one was already set in the logout URL
        $redirect = home_url( user_trailingslashit( 'my-account' ) );
    }

    return $redirect;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook it to `wp_logout` actions hook and remove the `wp_logout();` from the function. It'll look like below-

```
add_action('wp_logout', 'wc_registration_redirect');

function wc_registration_redirect( $redirect_to) {
    wp_redirect( '/my-account');
    exit;
}
```